# Using a variable in security group ingress cli command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-security-group

I am trying to run the following command by reading cidr ips out of a txt file.

`aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id $sgid --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 9092, "ToPort": 9092, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": '${cidreip}', "Description": "$train us-east-2"}]}]'`

When I try this with a single quote around my variable for cidr ip, I get the below error.
`Error parsing parameter '--ip-permissions': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 87 (char 86)`

Trying it with a double quote around the variable, the command takes it as a literal value. Not a variable.

How do I work around it? I tried escaping. I tried using the following

`aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id $sgid --ip-permissions "[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 9092, "ToPort": 9092, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "$cidreip", "Description": "$train us-east-2"}]}]"`
and I get a `Error parsing parameter '--ip-permissions': Invalid JSON:` error.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First JSON does not use `'`, but you need `"`. Also you have to build your string in chunks:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id 33333 --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 9092, "ToPort": 9092, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "'${cidreip}'", "Description": "'${train}' us-east-2"}]}]'
```